# Transformation between the same rotation expressed in different coordinate systems

Tags: transformation, rotations

**EDIT**

Lets assume my transformation does the following mapping:

\begin{align*}
x = -y  \\ 
y = -x  \\
z = -z
\end{align*}

Which produces this transformation matrix $R_t$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

A rotation around the $x$-axis, $R_{x}$ in one coordinate system should equal a rotation around the negative $y$-axis, $R_{-y}$, in the other coordinate system. Why is this relation not satisfied?

$I = R_x^{-1}*R_t*R_{-y}$

---

I'm a bit confused, so bear with me if I don't make total sense. I have two sets of rotations, $R_{1,k}$ and $R_{2,k}$,  $k =1,\dots,N$ expressed in different coordinate systems. I want to find the transformation, $R_t$ between these coordinate systems, such that

$I = R_{2,k}^{-1} * R_t * R_{1,k}$

If $R_{1,k}$ represents the same rotation as $R_{2,k}$. I'm doing an optimization approach, using the above function as a cost function. I'm not getting the results I expecting. I know for a fact that $R_1$ and $R_2$ represent the same rotations and that the transformation between the coordinate systems is constant. Even then, I receive different $R_t$ depending on how $R_1$ and $R_2$ looks.

What is it Im doing wrong? Is it even possible to find such a transformation?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess you really mean "I have *one* set of rotations expressed in *two* different coordinate systems."? That's what the context seems like. I guess it would also make sense as "two sets of matrices representing one set of rotations in two different coordinates."

Comment: Yes,thats a much better explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When we say a rotation around the x-axis in one system is the same as a rotation around the negative y-axis in the other system, what this really means is that you can transform your coordinates from the first system to the second, do your rotation around the negative y-axis, and then *transform the result back to the first system*, and what you end up with (the result of applying three transformation matrices) is the same thing you could have gotten by just rotating around the x-axis in the original coordinates.

In other words,

$$ R_x = R_t^{-1} R_{-y}\, R_t. $$

Equivalently,

$$ I = R_x^{-1} R_t^{-1} R_{-y}\, R_t. $$

In your particular case, since $R_t^{-1} = R_t$, you could just as well write

$$ I = R_x^{-1} R_t\, R_{-y}\, R_t^{-1}. $$

That is why $R_x^{-1} R_t\, R_{-y}$ is not coming out equal to the identity matrix. You need another factor of $R_t$.

Finding $R_t$ via this equation is more difficult than it would be if $R_t$ appeared only once. You might be better off looking for the axis of rotation of each of your known rotations, and compute a matrix that transforms three of these axes in the first coordinate system (not all in the same plane) to the corresponding rotation axes in the other system.

Answer (score -1):

Solving the equation $I = R_{2,k}^{-1} * R_t * R_{1,k}$ for $R_t$, you would conclude that $R_{2,k}*R_{1,k}^{-1} = R_t$.

Comment: The problem is, I get different $R_t$ for different $k$, even though the transformation should be the same between each pair of matrices.

Comment: @Eric I believe you! But how will your equation hold unless they all agree? It looks like there is something you may be assuming or missing that is causing this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm the problem! I've edited my original post with an example. Maybe you'll be able to see where my assumptions are not correct. Thank you!